# App crashes when getContext() is used to generate Toast inside fragment in API 23 but works on API 27 and more

Tags: java, android

When I try to generate a toast in **onCreateView** method of **ContestFragment** using context from  getContext(), the app crashes in Android Marshmallow while it works on Android Oreo and above. However, replacing getContext() with getContext().getApplicationContext() fixes the issue for Marshmallow. Can anyone please describe why is this happening?

Note: getContext() is not returning null. I have checked that.

```
public class ContestFragment extends Fragment {
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contest, container, false);
          Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //crashes at this line

         //Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "No Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
         //works

          return view;
      }
}
```

Error Log:

```
09-28 20:42:36.325 31550-31550/com.hitesh.codeforces E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hitesh.codeforces, PID: 31550
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hitesh.codeforces/com.hitesh.codeforces.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class TextView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class TextView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:432)
        at com.hitesh.codeforces.ContestFragment.onCreateView(ContestFragment.java:66)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1266)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6943)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3276)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class TextView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:432) 
        at com.hitesh.codeforces.ContestFragment.onCreateView(ContestFragment.java:66) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1266) 
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6943) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3276) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=16; index=528
        at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:66)
        at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:459)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:1167)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:197)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getString(TintTypedArray.java:150)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:397)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:209)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.A
```

XML (fragment_contest.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ContestFragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/include"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Show Finished"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/include" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try getActivity() ?

Comment: try requireContext() or maybe view.context, but i recommend you to show the toast in the onViewCreated method because you received the inflated view in the onCreateView and is a good place to show the message, after to inflate the view

Comment: Please, post your crash log so we can analyze it

Comment: @BogdanAndroid log added..

Comment: @JakeB getAvtivity() gives same error

Comment: @ManuelMato none worked for Marshmallow.

Comment: please share file XML(R.layout.fragment_contest)

Comment: @JavadDehban XML added to post

Comment: have you recently changed your code???
I think line error changed.

Comment: no, i changed nothing

Comment: please share XML file  MainActivity.I'm sure there is a problem with the XML.

Comment: @JavadDehban https://github.com/mitrukahitesh/Codeforces-Contests.git  Link to my project. Try to build the project (by replacing getContext().getApplicationContext() with getContext()) and open the app without internet connection. It is supposed to generate a toast "No Internet" but it crashes at that point.

Comment: yes, not worked because the problem is not to show the toast, it is to inflate the view... after my response, there weren´t logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is in font style file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="title">Code Forces</item>
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">0.08</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>
```

you can not use of   `<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>`

you can use

1- change to   `<item name="android:fontFamily">@string/font</item>`

2- in string file add line    `<string name="font" translatable="false">sans-serif-light</string>`

result:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="title">Code Forces</item>
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">0.08</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@string/font</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But if this was the error, then why was it working with getApplicationContext() ?

Comment: And is there any specific reason for "<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>" to not work in Marshmallow but work in other higher Android versions?